# Search and Replace Similar but Different Phrases

Tags: search, find

How do I search and replace a common, but different, phrase to a single phrase in multiple files from the terminal.

For instance, I want to change the following:

File1, File2, File3:

   --Link2-- --Link2-- --Link2--

   --Link3-- --Link3-- --Link3--

   --Link4-- --Link4-- --Link4--

ALL TO

--Link1--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether you could represent the "common but different phrases" by regex, you could use the following from the folder containing the files:

**Search n replace with Perl**
Syntax:
$ `perl -p -i -e 's/search_for/replace_with/g' filename(s)`

- `-e` is for "execute" – It allows you to define Perl code to be executed by the compiler
- `-p` is for "process" – It adds a loop around your `-e` code so that it is applied to each line of any specified files
- `-i` creates a backup file before making your changes.
- `-i.bak` suffixes `.bak` to the filename. If `-i` has no arguments, the file names don’t change.